# Retrieve an integer from the byte buffers read from the socket is implementation-defined?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider we have a sequence of bytes whose value representation like the following

```cpp
00000000, 00000000, 00000001, 00000000
```

It designates the integer value `256` on machine `A`, which is encoded by big-endian. Assume the destination machine is little-endian. Now, we have common functions like that

```cpp
unsigned long octets_to_unsigned32_little_endian(unsigned char *p)
{
  return p[0] | 
    ((unsigned)p[1]<<8) |
    ((unsigned long)p[2]<<16) |
    ((unsigned long)p[3]<<24);
}
/* long octets_to_signed32_little_endian(unsigned char *p)
{
  unsigned long as_unsigned = octets_to_unsigned32_little_endian(p);
  if (as_unsigned < 0x80000000)
    return as_unsigned;
  else
    return (long)(as_unsigned^0x80000000UL)-0x40000000L-0x40000000L;
} */
```

However, [basic.types.general] p4 says

> For trivially copyable types, **the value representation** is a set of bits in the object representation that determines a value, which is one discrete element of an **implementation-defined** set of values.

In the above example, regardless of how we retrieve the integer from the buffers, it always depends on how the value representation of the integer is. In other words, the implementation of the above functions always assumes the value representation of the integer value in the destination machine is `00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000`. In other words, the implementation can consider the value representation of the value `256` to be `00000000 10000000 00000000 0000000`, or `00000000 11111111 10101010 0000000`, or anyway, which does not violate the requirement of the standard.

#### Two questions

> 1. Retrieve an integer from the byte buffers is implementation-defined?
> 2. Is there any way that can get rid of implementation-defined?

Comment: Note that [std::byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) exist.

Comment: "Two questions" - Please always only ask **one** question per StackOverflow question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't think `std::byte` has some relevance for the value representation of an integer type.

Comment: @JesperJuhl They are the same question, the second relies on that the first opinion is true.

Comment: "Now, we have common functions like that" no we do not, we use `ntohl()` function

Comment: C++20 requires twos compliment representation for all integer types.

Comment: I think https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#fundamental-1.sentence-5 is intended to require that the whole range are valid values with a value representation and I would also expect that https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#fundamental-5 is supposed to imply that the coefficients in the base-2 representation correspond to bits in the value representation (although it doesn't actually seem to say that). For `|` it then doesn't matter how bits are valued, the value produced by with same values as operand is always the same, and shift and conversion operate on values, not representations.

Comment: @xmh0511: There [is no "`[basic.types.general]`" in C++20](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.types). The C++23 working draft renames "[basic.types]" to "[basic.types.general]", but that's a C++23 change.

Comment: Actually nevermind, it doesn't matter whether the base-2 representation corresponds to bits in the value representation, because the description of the bitwise operations has also been clarified to operate on the base-2 representation, not the object or value representation.

Comment: @user17732522 The bit operation is based on base-2 representation, which is defined in the standard, that's right. However, retrieving the integer from a sequence of eight-bit value by the bit operation is based on that we can recognize what the value the eight-bits designates in the destination machine, which still involves the value representation.

Comment: That's a matter of the network protocol though, isn't it? Reading from the socket is going to give you a sequence of bytes/char, not bits, and the expectation would be that the values of these match on sender and receiver side. Is there even any way to e.g. identify the state of individual bits in the value representation? The only operations that could tell me whether the n-th bit is set are operating on the arithmetic base-2 representation.

Comment: @user17732522 *I would also expect that eel.is/c++draft/basic#fundamental-5 is supposed to imply that the coefficients in the base-2 representation correspond to bits in the value representation (although it doesn't actually seem to say that).* Actually, the standard does not guarantee this point, see https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/131#issuecomment-1241970151. As said above, the taken each byte from a 32-bit integer object itself does involve the value representation.

Comment: The bit operation that tries to retrieve the integer in the destination machine does depend on the assumption that each eight-bit value in the source machine can represent the same value as that in the destination machine, which is implementation-defined. For instance, the standard does not guarantee that the eight-bit value `00000001` in any machine designates the integer value `1`.

Comment: So the situation you are looking at is that the sender is sending each bit one-by-one  in order from its physical memory / value representation, then the receiver also puts these bits one-by-one in order directly into its physical memory / value representation. In that case I suppose if the receiver doesn't know the value representation -> value mapping used by the sender it has no way of knowing what the intended values were. But that's just failure to establish a communication protocol, the same way that just sending native endianess would leave the receiver unable to understand the data.

Comment: @user17732522 Hence, send each byte one by one by the order of big-endian, and the receiver read the big-endian and then fills them into its value representation one by one in its native endian does result in an implementation-defined integer value. They eventually do involve the implementation-defined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You're not really doing operations on the value representation. You're not casting encoded values or anything.

You're doing *mathematics*.

`p[1]<<8` is a math operation, [mathematically equivalent to multiplying the numerical value at `p[1]` by the decimal value "256".](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.shift#2) Math defines the result of that operation.

Similarly, doing a bitwise `|` operation is mathematics. [You take the two numbers represented in binary, and perform a bitwise "or" on them, which results in a new binary value.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.or) Math defines the result of *that* operation too.

The value representation only matters to the extent that the *result* of the math can be completely encoded in that value representation. The value representation is where you get the numbers from, and where the numbers go to, but what happens in the middle is just doing math on numbers.

Comment: That's right that the bit operation is defined for base-2 representation, which only involves mathematical calculation. The declaration `unsigned char buff[] = {0,0,1,0}; ` is a bit misleading. Consider we have the bytes sequence like `00000000, 00000000, 00000001, 00000000`. What the integer value the eight-bit value designate in the destination machine is still implementation-defined. For instance, we know the value `256` in the source machine can be represented as `00000000, 00000000, 00000001, 00000000` and we know the third eight-bit part designates the value `1`...

Comment: ... so that we can use the bit operation `1 << 8`, which is equivalent to `1* 2^8` to retrieve the value, the calculation itself does not involve the value representation. However, it is not clear whether the eight-bit `00000001` in the destination machine designate the integer value `1` or not. Hence, the bit operation that is based on the assumption that `00000001` means `1` in the destination machine is meaningless.

Comment: @xmh0511: "*Hence, the bit operation that is based on the assumption that 00000001 means 1 in the destination machine is meaningless.*" There is no such "assumption". The mathematical concept of 2 can be represented in decimal as "2". It can be represented in binary as "10". Both of these are *the same number*.

Comment: Bitwise operations are defined based on a binary representation of the value. It doesn't matter if the implementation-defined representation is *not* binary; the job of the implementation is to implement the specification's defined behavior. If it decides to represent "2" with a bit sequence of "01101001", that's fine. But if you do a bitwise "or" with that and the number "1", you had better get whatever bit sequence corresponds to the number "3". Otherwise, the implementation is broken.

Comment: The base-2 representation is not equivalent to the value representation. https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/131#issuecomment-1241641503. `10` designate the value `2` is its base-2 representation on mathematical. However, whether such a set of bits in a machine designates `2` or not is implementation-defined.

Comment: @xmh0511: I don't see what that has to do with the results of the bitwise operation, which is specifically *not* about the value representation in any way, shape, or form (unless the value representation is binary).

Comment: *If it decides to represent "2" with a bit sequence of "01101001", that's fine.* That is the point here. `0000 0001` in the machine `A` designates integer value `1`, and we can retrieve the integer value `256` through such a byte in the same machine with the operation `c << 8`. However, with the hypothetical implementation `B` that `0000 0001` designate the integer value `100`, `100 << 8` can not retrieve the value `256` anyway.

Comment: @xmh0511: I don't understand. `100 << 8` is not supposed to yield 256. It's supposed to be 25600. I don't get what you're talking about.

Comment: Because the standard only defines the result of the bit operation on a determined value, which is based on base-2 representation, which does not involve the value representation. However, `serialize/deserialize` an integer value from a sequence of bytes transferred over the socket does involve the value representation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248089/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-xmh0511).